# Inserting an array with single quotes(') in database with perl DBI

Tags: mysql, perl

I am trying to insert an array into database and my query is as below:

**DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 8 bind variables when 3 are needed at main.pl line 114,  line 7.**

```
my $sql_in = "INSERT INTO $table VALUES(?,?,?,'','','','')";
my $stmt_in = $dbh->prepare($sql_in) or die "Couldn't prepare statement: ".$dbh->errstr;
$stmt_in->execute($q_num,$datatype,@qq) or die "Couldn't execute statement:".$stmt_in->errstr;
$stmt_in->finish;
```

@qq contains below test:

> Reporting that one of @its many problems had been the recent@ extended
>   sales slump in women's apparel, the seven-store retailer said it would
>   start a three-month liquidation sale in all of its stores. 
>   (A) its many problems had been the recent (B) its many problems has been the
>   recently (C) its many problems is the recently (D) their many problems
>   is the recent (E) their many problems had been the recent

Comment: Can you show the actual code that creates your `@qq` please

Comment: The error message says `@qq` has 8 values and should contain 3. We know it should contain 3, as there are 3 question marks in the premare statement. But we can't tell from your description how many values it actually contains, nor whether the prepare statement is correct. What are the column names of your table `$table`?

Comment: "@qq contains below test" - that's not really helpful. `@qq` is an array and you've told us that it contains a single scalar value. Is this text split across various elements of `@qq`? It is all in `$qq[0]`? Are the other values in other elements of `@qq`?

Comment: I have changed my approach, but for understanding: @qq contains 6 elements(6 lines).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each SQL parameter (`?`) must receive *exactly one* value when you execute the query.  The array `@qq` contains multiple values.  Based on the error message, the array must contain six elements.

Looking at your query, I'm guessing that you want the entire content of the array to go into a single field.  If so, you should be able to use

```
$stmt_in->execute($q_num,$datatype, join("\n", @qq)) or die...
```

to achieve this, possibly replacing the `\n` with another character/string that you want inserted between the array's values.

Alternately, if you want to insert only the first element in the array (which could be the case since the question only shows a single element), use

```
$stmt_in->execute($q_num,$datatype,$qq[0]) or die...
```

If you want to insert all array elements with each element going into a separate field in the table, you need to construct a query with the right number of placeholders, most likely by using `join(', ', ('?') x @qq)` if the array's size is variable.

Comment: I used the approach of replacing all the '\n' with a special character. This worked. Thanks for different options in the answer.